# Rails 3 DateTime Comparison w/ Date In An ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, datetime, activerecord

I'm trying to search a model for any dates equal to a specific date while omitting the timestamp. In Rails I could simply execute this as `DateTime.to_date == somedate`, however I don't think it's quite as easy to formulate in SQL where I wouldn't be able to apply the to_date method to an entire column like created_at:

```
Foo.where("created_at == some_day_without_time_stamp").count
```

Initially I thought that because I was using a postgresql database I could simply use psql syntax, but I much much rather leave it to ActiveRecord to decide what sql is most applicable and keep my code agnostic of database vendors. Is this possible without any additional plugins or gems?

Comment: Can you do created_at >= some_day_with_00:00:00 timestamp and create_at < some_day_plus_one_with_00:00:00 timestamp?

Comment: @Tad Evidently I can, thanks for the help. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You're welcome - answer added below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `created_at >= some_day_with_00:00:00 timestamp and create_at < some_day_plus_one_with_00:00:00 timestamp`

Answer (score 11):

I would do something like...

```
someday = Date.today
Foo.where( :created_at => (someday)..(someday + 1.day) )
```

This would capture all `created_at` dates between midnight on `someday` and `someday + 1`. This is inclusive (so it would include a Foo created bang on midnight on the +1 day) but may be 'just good enough' for your needs without messing with timestamps.

For niceness, I would wrap it up as a `scope`

```
scope :on_day, ( lambda do |someday|
  where( :created_at => (someday)..(someday + 1.day) )
end )
```

So

```
Foo.on_day( Date.yesterday ).count
```

is nicely readable.

Comment: You have an off by one, which could lead to you counting a day twice. This was my fix: 
`where( :created_at => (someday)..(someday + 23.hours + 59.minutes + 59.seconds) )`

Answer (score 9):

DateTime class have two usefull methods to do this: `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day`.

For this case, in which you have a Date object, you might do:

```
Foo.where('created_at >= #{Date.today.to_time.beginning_of_day} AND 
           created_at <= #{Date.today.to_time.end_of_day}')
```

Notice that you have to **transform the Date object to a DateTime object**

Answer (score 7):

With scope:

```
scope :on_day, (lambda do |day|
   where(date: day.beginning_of_day..day.end_of_day)
end)
```

Using:

```
Foo.on_day(Date.today).count
```