# Can't find record by Date [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm having the problem that I can't find records by searching in a datetime attribute.
I have a flight model that has a datetime attribute called date. From a form I'm getting a value in the format `%d/%m/%Y` and I'm proceeding to execute a query using that information, but it always returns en empty ActiveRelation.

Some things I've tried:

```
Flight.first.date == params[:date] 
#=> true 

Date.parse(params[:date]) == Flight.first.date 
#=>true

Flight.where(date: params[:date])
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "flights".* FROM "flights" WHERE "flights"."date" = ?  [["date", "30/03/2015"]]
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
Flight.where(date: Date.parse(params[:date]))
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "flights".* FROM "flights" WHERE "flights"."date" = '2015-03-30'
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>


#params[:date] is equal to "30/03/2015"

First.flight.date #is equal to Mon, 30 Mar 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should be using `Date.parse(params[:date])` to convert it into a useful form like you have here. Do you have a `DATE` column? Careful when comparing a `DATE` to a `DATETIME`, as the latter has a hours+minutes+seconds component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to compare flights to a date range

```
parsed_datetime = DateTime.parse(params[:date])
Flight.where(date: (parsed_datetime)..(parsed_datetime + 1.day))
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13700805/4640187

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Flight.where(["date like ?", "%#{Date.parse(params[:date])}%"])
```

Or

```
Flight.where(["date like ?", "%#{params[:date].to_date}%"])
```